# Flask Jinja Route

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

What is the correct syntax for the href on an html page with Jinja2 code, that allows for navigation between two pages?  The first html template has a list of names, while the other has person details.

Here is the code I have for the listOfNames.html page that displays the list of names.

```
<ul>
    {% for rownum, row in listNames.iterrows() %}
        <li><a href="/listNames/person/{{row.personId}}">{{ row.firstName }} {{ row.lastName }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Here is the server.py code that gets/puts (correct use of term?) the names on the listOfNames.html.

```
@app.route('/listNames/<bo>/')
def listNames(bo):
    listNames = getListNames(bo)
    return render_template('listOfNames.html', listNames=listNames)
```

This is code for the personInformation.html.

```
<main role="main" class="col-sm-9 ml-sm-auto col-md-10 pt-3">
    <h1>{{ person.firstName }}
            {{ person.lastName }}
    </h1>
    <h2>Office:
          {{ person.bo }}
    </h2>
    <h2>Courses Completed
    </h2>
        <ul>
            {% for rownum, row in personCompleted.iterrows() %}
            <li><a href="/courses/{{row.courseId}}">
                {{row.courseTitle}}
            </a></li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
     </main>
```

And here is the server.py code.

```
    @app.route('/people/<person_id>')
def person(person_id):
    person = getPersonOrganization(person_id)
    personCompleted = getPersonCompleted(person_id)
    return render_template('personInformation.html',  person=person, personCompleted=personCompleted)
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is by using the `url_for()` function from Flask. Here is your new `listOfPeople.html` template with the link:

```
<ul>
    {% for rownum, row in listNames.iterrows() %}
        <li><a href="{{ url_for('person', person_id=row.personId) }}">{{ row.firstName }} {{ row.lastName }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

It's best to not hardcode your URLs in the templates, because if you ever need to reorganize them, then you would need to update URLs all over the place. With `url_for()` Flask takes care of generating the URLs for you using the information you provided in the `app.route` decorators.

Comment: Miguel.  This is awesome, thank you!  The modification gets me to the main list of all people, so I think I'm missing something in the href.

Comment: Sorry, not  missing anything, I had to update the model.py file with the right query.